# google analytics in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, google-analytics, web-statistics

I am using asp.net 3.5 with C#.

I have registered my application in google analytics and it is successfully showing my statistics. But I want to integrate that statistics into my website, is there any way I can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to retrieve Analytics data (rather than collect it, as it sounds like you're already doing), take a look at Google's [Data Export API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataDeveloperGuide.html)

Comment: I am using this http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/2.0/gdataJavascript.html 
Javascript version, but it seems that it's not working for me, I am getting no error which I can discuss here, I am pressing "Access Google Analytics" and after that I am getting loading button .. but no data or analytics .. :(

Comment: Please suggest how can I acheive it

Comment: How are you running the sample? I found that it doesn't work if you load the page from your local hard drive (i.e. with a file:// url) but does it you upload it to a live server (with an http:// url). I don't know if http:// localhost works. Also, are you building the html/js files according to their tutorials or have you tried copying the completed samples they give you?

Comment: Here's my (working) copy of the example code: http://dahveed.dyndns.org/stackoverflow/analytics/

Comment: Dave Kilian - Du you have that sample code left? I'm having the same problem. Thx

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [Google Analytics API](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gaJS/gaJSApi.html)? It's javascript, but you can get that data into server-side code from there.

Comment: Can I get any widget kind of report, all I found on the net is something which requires login.
Also I have checked the link provided by Dave, it's fine but alas... not working for me.